# Robust approach to migrating SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I am trying to migrate my SQL Server 2008 R2 DB to SQL Azure.

Currently I believe that the SQLAzure MIgration Wizard is the best tool to migrate SqlServer DBs to Azure. I am trying this option.... Also getting connection errors. Is this tool still the best approach if and when I get the connection issues sorted.

I am also thinking of VS Data Tools for Schema and Data comparison features, and syncing between the two.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure Migration Wizard may be the appropriate tool for you depending on your databases size and complexity. If your database is "large" (> 200 MB) you'll want a tool that can automatically retry throttled operations. Luckily, SQL Azure Migration Wizard has good data efficiency. However, this tool is not supported by Microsoft. You might look into sql server data tools if you need the Microsoft support.

Extra information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj156172.aspx